# Why does this Javascript object not go out of scope after $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have some working Javascript that manipulates the some DOM elements. The problem is, I don't understand *why* it works, which is never a good thing. I am trying to learn more about object oriented javascript and javascript best practices, so the organization may seems a little strange.

Basically, I wrap two methods that manipulate the DOM inside a `CSContent` object. I create an instance of that object, `content` in `$(document).ready` and bind some events to the functions in `content`. However, I am confused as to how these functions can still be called after `$(document).ready` exits. Doesn't that mean that `content` has gone out of scope, and its functions are not available? Anyway, here is the code:

```
function CSContent() {
    var tweetTextArea = document.getElementById('cscontent-tweet'),
        tweetTextElement = document.getElementById('edit-cscontent-cs-content-tweet'),
        charCountElement = document.getElementById('cscontent-tweet-charactercount');

    this.toggleTweetTextarea = function () {
      $(tweetTextArea).slideToggle();
    };

    this.updateTweetCharacterCount = function () {
        var numOfCharsLeft = 140 - tweetTextElement.value.length;
        if (numOfCharsLeft < 0) {
            $(charCountElement).addClass('cscontent-negative-chars-left');
        }
        else {
            $(charCountElement).removeClass('cscontent-negative-chars-left');
        }
        charCountElement.innerHTML = '' + numOfCharsLeft + ' characters left.';
    };
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = new CSContent();
    //If the twitter box starts out unchecked, then hide the text area
    if ($('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-twitter:checked').val() === undefined) {
        $('#cscontent-tweet').hide();
    }

    $('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-twitter').change(content.toggleTweetTextarea);
    //Seems wasteful, but we bind to keyup and keypress to fix some weird miscounting behavior when deleting characters.
    $('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-tweet').keypress(content.updateTweetCharacterCount);
    $('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-tweet').keyup(content.updateTweetCharacterCount);
    content.updateTweetCharacterCount();
});
```

Comment: Can you show an example of where you have access to `content` where you shouldn't have?

Comment: @Pekka: when in element with id `edit-cscontent-cs-content-tweet` a key is pressed or depressed, for instance?

Comment: @Marcel ahh, that's what he meant! That is a closure. But you're already explaining that in your answer - would +1 but I'm out of votes for today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wonder why the event handlers like

```
$('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-twitter').change(content.toggleTweetTextarea);
```

work?

Well you don't pass `content` as event handler but the function that is contained in `content.toggleTweetTextarea`. And this reference will still exist after `content` does not exist anymore. There is nothing special about it. You just assigned an object (the function) to another variable. As long as at least one reference to an object exists, the object won't be garbage collected.

Now you may ask why those functions have still access to e.g. `tweetTextArea` ? This is indeed a closure. When the functions are created via `new CSContent()`, the activation context of this function is added to the scope chain of the inner functions `CSContent.toggleTweetTextarea` and `CSContent.updateTweetCharacterCount`. So even if you don't have a reference to `content` anymore, the scope of this function is still contained in the scope chain of the other functions.

You won't be able to access the object contained in `content` anymore after `ready()` is finished, this indeed goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

This, m'lord, is called a closure: the local variable `content` will remain in memory after `$(document).ready` exits. This is also a known cause of memory leaks.

In short, you bind this function to an event listener of a DOM element and then the JavaScript garbage collector knows that it should keep the local variable intact. You can't call it directly (outside of the function), unless the event is triggered. With some, you can do this ‘manually’, if you really want to call the function afterward (e.g., using `element.click()` to simulate a click).

Comment: But other than that, they are great! :) Some additional reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: So it can access to the local variables declared in the CSContent constructor because it is a closure, and it doesn't go out of scope because it is bound to an event listener? Or does the whole closure get copied somehow to the event listener?

Answer (score 1):

My brain is off today, but shouldn't you be using closures in this situation?

```
$('#edit-cscontent-cs-content-twitter').change( 
    function(){ 
        content.toggleTweetTextarea(); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: Today....?    :)    Hey Eric did you ever see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274044/best-book-on-ajax/3306936#3306936

Comment: Hmm, good idea, closures. But the OP is already using one… :P